# Cannot connect to Redis from Laravel Application

Tags: docker, redis

I have to configure Redis with Socketio in my Laravel application. However, what ever I have tried so far, I get the same error:

**Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] i**

I can go to the container with docker exec -it id sh and when I ping the server I get the PONG message. Client is already 'predis' in my database.php file and package also installed.

**.env**

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: "2"
    services:
      api:
        build: .
        ports:
          - 9000:9000
        volumes:
          - .:/app
          - /app/vendor
        depends_on:
          - postgres
          - redis
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://xx@postgres/xx
      postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: xx
          POSTGRES_DB: xx
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xx
        volumes:
          - .Data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
          - 3306:5432
      redis:
        build: ./Redis/
        ports:
          - 6003:6379
        volumes:
          - ../RedisData/data:/data
        command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```

**Dockerfile (redis)**

```
FROM redis:alpine

COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

Comment: How do you read your `.env` file? The error is too obviously saying your host is set to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: redis host is running on the container ports 0.0.0.0:6003->6379/tcp. DB_HOST=postgres is running without problem. What I'm missing here? @AlexKarshin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is saying it can connect to `127.0.0.1` on port `6379`. So make sure the host and port is ok:

- host 127.0.0.1 is ok: this work if you run the php on the same host than redis, or if you run php on Docker host machine, but in this case, the port will be `6003`
- port 6379 is ok: host is not good, you must specify the Docker container hostname: `redis`
- make sure configuration cache is ok

Answer (score 1):

Set your REDIS_HOST to redis like this REDIS_HOST=redis. The reason is that you already built your docker file and specified redis as the name of your redis service

Answer (score 0):

Had Same issue...

Also updated following in **redis.conf**

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

To

```
bind redis
```

as redis is the existing host now